# For loop in javascript with empty body - is there a better way to do it?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I've got a code like this one:

```
var ccode = [
    ["de", "de", ".de.example.com"],
    ["uk", "uk", ".uk.example.com"],
    ["uk", "nl", ".nl.example.com"],
    ["pl", "pl", ".pl.example.com"]
];
var lng;
var gamepage;
var reg;
var gamepages = {}
{
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < ccode.length && !(document.location.href.search(ccode[i][1] + ".example.com") != -1); i++) {}
    lng = ccode[i][0];
    gamepage = ccode[i][2];
    reg = new RegExp("http://s(\\d+)\\." + ccode[i][1] + "\\.example\\.com/(.*?)\\.php(.*)", "i");
    gamepages[ccode[i][1]] = "http://www" + ccode[i][2];
}
```

It works but.. It look like crap, is there a better way to do it? If you need a background it looks for "de" or "en" in the page's URL adress and sets the variables to change the language.

Thank for your help. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ccode.forEach(function(code){
    if(document.location.href.search(code[1] + "example.com"){
        lng = code[0];
    }
});
```

This is how I would solve it. For loop is avoided, and intention is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something with each of the items on `ccode`, right? `for` means a lot of boilerplate just for that... try `[].forEach()`!

```
var ccode = [
    ["de", "de", ".de.example.com"],
    ["uk", "uk", ".uk.example.com"],
    ["uk", "nl", ".nl.example.com"],
    ["pl", "pl", ".pl.example.com"]
];

ccode.forEach(function(c) {
    // c will be ["de", "de", ".de.example.com"] at first, and so on...

    if ((document.location.href.search(c + ".example.com") != -1)) return;

    console.log(c)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for...in` loop. Using a `for...in` loop on an array only iterates the enumerable properties of the array.

Then I would use `match` to test the url, because you can reliably coerce a boolean from the result using `!!`.

I added a default array option, otherwise it would use the last item iterated, even if no items were matched. This way you can explicitly tell the script to stop (or otherwise handle the condition) if no items were matched.

Also, some RegEx simplifications.

```js
var lng, gamepage, reg, gamepages = {}
var ccode = [
    ["de", "de", ".de.example.com"],
    ["uk", "uk", ".uk.example.com"],
    ["uk", "nl", ".nl.example.com"],
    ["pl", "pl", ".pl.example.com"],
    ["", "", ""] // default to signal if nothing found.
];

//  Loop the array    Test the locatio, if it matches break the loop
for(var i in ccode) !!location.href.match(ccode[i][1]+'.example.com') && break;

if(!ccode[i][0]) return; // stop now if there was nothing found.

lng = ccode[i][0];
gamepage = ccode[i][2];
reg = new RegExp("http://s(\\d+)."+ccode[i][1]+".example.com/([^.]+).php(.*)", "i");
gamepages[ccode[i][1]] = "http://www" + ccode[i][2];
```